# user input handling

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-input

How do you guys handle using the same form to input and edit data. I currently check to see if a param has been parsed in the form or querystring and action accordingly.  e.g

```
string id = Request.QueryString.Get("id");

if(id == string.Empty){
  //new input
}else{
  //get data from database etc
  //populate form
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally i use hidden text box to store current record id and check same way as you did. But difference is, I use post not get.

And also use dynamic submit destination - for insert or update functions

I am not sure its a best way to implement that

Comment: I always use the same submit destination and just call an update or insert based on whether its new data or updating data.

Answer (score 0):

Use Session, Session["ID"] = "ObjectID";

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["ID"])){
//new input
}else{
//get data from database etc
//populate form
}
```